# Python Dash - Updating Drop Downs

Tags: plotly-dash

I am making a dashboard in Python using Dash. I have a couple of questions about my code and how to improve it.

### Context:

I have a lot of data (like 12M+ rows and ~30 columns) that I put into a SQLite database. The SQLite database is still pretty big (like 2GB). I don't need all of this data, and I have a query that does transformations in there (summing up columns grouped by a date field) which I then use for my dashboard for charts etc.

I want to give the user of the dashboard some flexibility to choose some filters to give a different type of view. For example, only selecting customers with "Product A" or only selecting male customers etc. So I have some dropdowns to select those options, which should then update the charts. This means that the SQL query gets re-run using these new filters.

### Questions

1. Is there a faster way to do this? What is weird is that when I run the query on my local machine, it takes less than 1 minute to run. But when I run the dashboard, when I update the drop downs, it takes more like 5-6 minutes, which will be unfeasible to use.
2. It seems like when I quickly change two or more options on the drop downs, it takes even longer to update. I'm guessing because it does each update separately? So it would be running the query multiple times? Is there a way to incorporate a button that will run the callback only when I hit it with the new inputs?

### Code for reference:

```
import os
import dash
import dash_table
import dash_core_components as dcc
import dash_html_components as html
import plotly.graph_objects as go
import pandas as pd
import sqlite3

app = dash.Dash()

app.layout = html.Div(children=[

    html.H1(children='Dashboard'),

    html.Div(children='''
        Dashboard)
    '''),

    dcc.Dropdown(
        id='filter1',
        options=[
            {'label': 'Filter1Option1', 'value': 1},
            {'label': 'Filter1Option2', 'value': 0}
        ],
        value=[0,1],
        multi=True
    ),

    dcc.Dropdown(
        id='filter2',
        options=[
            {'label': 'Filter2Option1', 'value': 1},
            {'label': 'Filter2Option2', 'value': 0}
        ],
        value=[0,1],
        multi=True
    ),
        
    dcc.Graph(
        id='myGraph'
    )
            
])

@app.callback(
    dash.dependencies.Output('myGraph', 'figure'),
    [dash.dependencies.Input('filter1', 'value'),
     dash.dependencies.Input('filter2', 'value')])
def update_everything(filter1, filter2):
    conn = sqlite3.connect('dashboard_data.sqlite')

    query = (
    """
    QUERY BASED ON FILTERS. INVOLVES SOME CALCULATIONS AND GROUPING BY A DATE FIELD
    """
    )

    df = pd.read_sql(query, conn)

    conn.close()


    fig = go.Figure(data=go.Scatter(x=df['DATE'], y=df['METRIC']))
    fig.update_layout(
        yaxis_tickformat='%',
        title='My Graph'
    )
                                                 
    return fig

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run_server(debug=True, host='0.0.0.0', port=8050)
```

Comment: Do you have multiple callbacks using the data or just one? How large is the data returned from the query, i.e. the df object in your code above?

Comment: I have just that one callback listed up there. It takes 3 inputs, and has 1 output (though would eventually like to expand to more outputs).

The df object, which is the result of the query, is around 20 or so rows and 10 columns.